# For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $ ab \le a^2 + b^2$

Tags: proof-writing

For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $ ab \le a^2 + b^2$

Just what the title says. Im a bit stuck here.

Edit:I'm thinking that since a and b are both reals, they can be either positive or negative, making ab either positive or negative. I also know that $a^2≥0$ as well as $b^2≥0$. I'm just have trouble making formalizing it.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a-b)^2 \geq 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: In my head, I'm thinking that since a and b are both reals, they can be either positive or negative, making ab either positive or negative. I also know that $a^2 \ge 0$ as well as $b^2 \ge 0$. I'm just have trouble making formalizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach**

\begin{align*}
a^{2} + b^{2} \geq ab & \Longleftrightarrow 2(a^{2} + b^{2}) \geq 2ab\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a^{2} - 2ab + b^{2}) + (a^{2} + b^{2}) \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a-b)^{2} + (a^{2} + b^{2}) \geq 0
\end{align*}

**Second approach**

\begin{align*}
a^{2} + b^{2} \geq ab & \Longleftrightarrow a^{2} - ab + b^{2} \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(a - \frac{b}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{3b^{2}}{4} \geq 0
\end{align*}

Comment: On the second line, how was $a^2 + b^2$ kept? I see how $2ab$ was moved over but what happened to the $2(a^2 + b^2)?$. (Sorry for the bother)

Comment: Notice that $2(a^{2} + b^{2}) = (a^{2} + b^{2}) + (a^{2} + b^{2})$. Then I've just gathered the first term with $-2ab$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I see now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.